# Create html datalist from xml file

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have following xml file which i want to load into a html datalist.
I used following example as reference but cant get it to work.
Any help would be appreciated.
[How to create custom datalist from XML file using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123200/how-to-create-custom-datalist-from-xml-file-using-jquery)
I could however change the format or structure of the xml file if needed.

The programs.xml and html file are in the same folder directory of course.
Somewhere in the script seems to be a problem because it does not load data from the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<frequencyList>
<program>"10000,5000,880,3000,95" value="Stomachache"<time>3</time></program>
<program>"2720,2170,880,787,727,190,500" value="Headache"<time>3</time></program>
<program>"20,146,727,776,787,880,10000" value="Toothache"<time>3</time></program>
</frequencyList>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
  <head>
    <title>Datalist</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
           $.get('programs.xml', function(xml){
                $(xml).find('program').each(function(){
                    var $program = $(this).text();
                    $('<option> data-value='+$program+'>').appendTo('#frequencyList')
                });
            });     
       });
    </script>
    
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" name="frequencyList" list="frequencyList">
  <datalist id="frequencyList"></datalist>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just checking: You're testing this through a web server and not just reading a local file, right? If not, you might be crossing a browser security policy in trying to read a local file from JavaScript.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: The output should be "<option data-value="10000,5000,880,3000,95" value="Stomachache">" so that i can feed it into the html datalist. I think the xml_parser like in my answer below would be the best solution?

Comment: @Daniel take a look here: https://codepen.io/rabbitjacktrade/pen/poRXYYX?editors=1011

Comment: Awesome @Jack. How do i need to adapt the code so it loads the programs.xml which is in the same directory as the html file? Instead of using the hardcoded xml string like your example. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not fix your code but have an idea how your problem could be solved:

```
var deinstring = '"10000,5000,880,3000,95"  value="Stomachache"';
var allesmussraus = deinstring.match(/value=\"(.*?)\"/)[0].trim().replace(/value=/g, '').replace(/['"]+/g, '');  //returns array
mydiv = document.getElementById("ausgabe").innerHTML = allesmussraus;
```

And HTML Code:

```
<div id="ausgabe">

</div>
```

The output of this is:

```
Stomachache
```

Maybe this can help you fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i need to load from a xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about using the xml_parser -> https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp
Does someone have experience with it and can assist?
I would just need to parse all the text in "program" and append it to the datalist :)

Appending with $(''+$program+'>').appendTo("#programList")
I still need to loop through all "program" in the xml and get the string out of it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var parser, xmlDoc;
var text = "<frequencyList>" +
"<program>"10000,5000,880,3000,95" value="Stomachache"<time>3</time></program>" +
"<program>"2720,2170,880,787,727,190,500" value="Headache"<time>3</time></program>" +
"<program>"20,146,727,776,787,880,10000" value="Toothache"<time>3</time></program>" +
"</frequencyList>";

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("program")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
</script>

    input type="text" id="list_input" list="programList" style="width: 220px;">
  <datalist id="programList">
  <option data-value="262,2154" value="Kopfweh">
  </datalist>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you really need jquery for this and also not sure I understand you correctly, but try changing your function to this:

```
function executeScript() {
  $xml 
    .find("program")
    .each(function(index) {
      $elem = "<option data-value=" + $(this).text() + ">"
      $($elem).appendTo("#programList")
    });
}
```

and see if it works.

Comment: This function looks like what i need it but does not append any text to programList :(

 `function executeScript() { 
  $.get('programs.xml', function(xml){
 $xml.find("program").each(function(index) {
 $elem = "<option data-value=" + $(this).text() + ">"
 $($elem).appendTo("#programList")
});
});  }`

Comment: @Daniel Not sure what the problem is, since I don't have access to `programs.xml`; the answer does work with the sample xml in your question.

Answer (score -1):

This code parses the string between `<program>` 
How to change it, so that it loads from the xml-file in the first question on top "programs.xml" which is in the same directory instead of a hardcoded xml string?
The output should be -> option data-value="10000,5000,880,3000,95" value="Stomachache"> so that i can feed it into the html datalist.

My idea is something like this but it doesnt load the xml.

```
    function executeScript() {
$(document).ready(function(){
       $.get('programs.xml', function(xml){
           $xml
            .find("program")
            .each(function(index) {
            $elem = "<option data-value=" + $(this).text() + ">";
            $($elem).appendTo("#programList")
            });   
        });     
   });    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
  <head>
    <title>Datalist</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <body onload="executeScript()">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><frequencyList>'+
    '<program>"10000,5000,880,3000,95" value="Stomachache"<time>3</time></program>'+
    '<program>"2720,2170,880,787,727,190,500" value="Headache"<time>3</time></program>'+
    '<program>"20,146,727,776,787,880,10000" value="Toothache"<time>3</time></program></frequencyList>';
    
    var $xml = $(xml);

    function executeScript() {
      $xml 
        .find("program")
        .each(function(index) {
          $elem = "<option data-value=" + $(this).text() + ">";
          $($elem).appendTo("#programList")
        });
    }

</script>
    
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" id="list_input" list="programList" style="width: 220px;">
  <datalist id="programList">
  <option data-value="262,2154" value="Kopfweh" time="3">
  </datalist>
</body>
</html>
```